# Check if a point is within a quadratic surface (with arbitrary rotation)

Tags: surfaces, quadratics

Is there a general way to check whether a point is on a quadratic surface given that the principal axes do not need to coincide with the coordinate axes and that the quadric's centroid does not need to coincide with the centroid of the coordinate system?

Going from the normal form of the quadric to a translated quadric is easy (subtracting the center from the point that is to be checked), but how can the rotation be taken into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ${\bf x} = A \bf X$, then ${\bf x}^T Q {\bf x} = {\bf X}^T A^T Q A \bf X $.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind defining the variables/matrices? I assume you build one of the matrices from the implicit form of the surface in 10 variables (like here: http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/geometry/simple.html)?

Comment: Quadric surface in general form, from that link: ${\bf x}^T Q \bf x = 0$, where ${\bf x} = \pmatrix{ x\cr y\cr z\cr 1\cr}$.